# How could i change the url when forwarding to a page

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, forward

I am trying to forward to a .jsp, but the url does not change. I clearly know the difference between redirect and forward, but I need to get the error information from servlet which will be displayed in jsp, for example:
login.jsp

```
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${error=='username'}">
       <div class="msg error" style="display:block">invalid username</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${error=='password'}">
       <div class="msg error" style="display:block">incorrect password</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <div class="msg error" style="display:block"></div>
    </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
 <form id="login-form" action="LoginAction" method="post" autocomplete="off" name="loginform" onsubmit="Check()">
    <ul class="scr-log-form-list">
       <li class="scr-form-item">
           <label for="username" class="prefix">username</label> 
           <input id="username" class="ipt" name="passport" type="text" placeholder="用户名" />
       </li>
       <li class="scr-form-item"><label for="password" class="prefix">password</label>
           <input id="password" class="pwd" name="password" type="password" /> 
           <input id="remember" class="remPwd" name="remember" value="true" type="checkbox" />
           <label for="remember" class="remPwdLabel">remember me</label>
       </li>
       <li class="scr-log-item">
           <a id="login" class="log-btn" onclick="javascript:document.loginform.submit();" style="cursor: hand" href="#"></a> 
           <span class="log-ing-btn"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </form>
```

here is LoginServlet:

```
        String username = (String) request.getParameter("passport");
        String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
        AjaxRequest ar = new AjaxRequest();
        User u = ar.getUserByName(username.trim());
        if (u == null) {
            //response.sendRedirect("index1.jsp?error=usename");
            request.setAttribute("error", "username");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index1.jsp").forward(request,
                    response);
        } else if (!u.getPasswd().equals(password.trim())) {
//          response.sendRedirect("index1.jsp?error=password");
            request.setAttribute("error", "password");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index1.jsp").forward(request,
                    response);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/mapviewer.jsp").forward(
                    request, response);
        }
```

I don't know how to change the url when using forward, but it is quite essential. for example if user types localhost:8080/project/LoginServlet, it will be 404 error, how could solve this problem

Comment: You can't; you'd have to redirect to change the URL.

Comment: Assuming you're setting errors inside of that, you could in theory just set it inside of your session for the user, then redirect them to the login page, you cant change the url with a forward though, they are server side only, and the client knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript for it.

```
<script>
 //get The current URL
 var currURL = ${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
 //Push the current URL to window history
 window.history.pushState("object or string", "mapviewer", currURL );
</script>
```

Put it at the top of JSP inside `<body>`, so that it executes first OR you can put it anywhere in the `<body>` .

Answer (score 0):

#### request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/mapviewer.jsp").forward(

```
                request, response); ####
```

Replace "/WEB-INF/mapviewer.jsp" with "mapviewer.jsp"
it will resolve your problem
Thanks
SP

Comment: is it secure to put mapviewer.jsp in root directory rather than WEB-INF?

Comment: Not not in root diectory.....If you are using eclipse ,then your .jsp file should be in WebContent Directory